# mysql searching text with search terms from second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in mysql.

One table called importcity has 6 columns of text.

The columns are: `agtrmks` ,  `agtrmks_2` ,  `agtrmks_3` ,  `pubrmrks` ,  `pubrmrks_2` ,  `pubrmrks_3`

The second table, called filter, has search terms. I want to delete any rows that from importcity that match any of the search terms. I was on the path of a correlated query but I couldn't figure that out. I also tried to concat the columns but I got stuck on the where and like clauses.

If I were to do it manually, this SQL statement works correctly

```
`DELETE FROM `importcity_houston` where lower(concat(`agtrmks`,`agtrmks_2`,`agtrmks_3`,`pubrmrks`,`pubrmrks_2`,`pubrmrks_3`))   REGEXP '(auction.com|bank of america|fannie|fha|freddie|homepath|homesteps|hubzu|hud|short sale)'`
```

But I want the regex part to be dynamically created from the terms in the filter table.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and search terms, along with what you expect to get out?

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure what you are looking for.  I am guessing that you have a bunch of search terms that you want to search for in any of the six fields. Instead of using `LIKE`, you could use `IN`.  It would look something like the following:

```
SELECT I.* 
FROM importcity_houston AS I
WHERE I.agtrmk IN ('FirstSearch', 'SecondSearch', 'ThirdSearch') OR
      I.agtrmks_2 IN ('FirstSearch', 'SecondSearch', 'ThirdSearch') OR
      I.agtrmks_3 IN ('FirstSearch', 'SecondSearch', 'ThirdSearch') OR
      I.pubrmrks IN ('FirstSearch', 'SecondSearch', 'ThirdSearch') OR
      I.pubrmrks_2 IN ('FirstSearch', 'SecondSearch', 'ThirdSearch') OR
      I.pubrmrks_3 IN ('FirstSearch', 'SecondSearch', 'ThirdSearch')
```

Comment: I want to do this: select terms from filter table and feed that into a delete from import city where search terms match any of the six columns. I hope that make more sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 DELETE from importcity
 WHERE agtrmks in (
   SELECT a.agtrmks 
   FROM (select i.agtrmks 
         FROM importcity i 
         cross join filter f on i.agtrmks = f.search_terms
         OR i.agtrmks_2 = f.search_terms 
         OR i.agtrmks_3 = f.search_terms 
         OR i.pubrmrks = f.search_terms 
         OR i.pubrmrks_2 = f.search_terms 
         OR i.pubrmrks_3 = f.search_terms 
        ) as a);
```

**[SQL Fiddle..](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/dd4b4/1/0)**